# To Show an tooltip on Image in Mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, tooltip

I'm using asp.net MVC3 and i want to show a table containing information about a course
In that i have a field called "Information" which show an image.
I want to show the a tooltip when the mouse is taken on that image

I'm showing image lik this:

```
<img id="ok" src="../../Images/info.jpg" alt="tooltip"/>
```

I dont want to use any added plugin

can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Check this: http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Display-beautiful-tooltips-in-Asp-Net-MVC

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `title` as well as `alt` in the Html tag

```
<img id="ok" src="../../Images/info.jpg" title="This is your tooltip message"/>
```

Comment: `alt` and `title` are for different things, OP still needs to use `alt` to have an alternate text for an image, if the image cannot be displayed. And `title` is for having additional info which is rendered in all modern browsers as a tooltip.

Comment: He's looking for a tooltip, title gives a tooltip, he can use both in case he's using FireFox which will not use the alt text as a tooltip

Comment: @CDSmith He should use the `alt` always. `alt` is not for tool tips, its an accessibility property. See my answer.

Comment: Yep, which is why I said to use title for the expected behavior: a tooltip on mouseover - which is what he asked for

Comment: @Curt I tried to upvote yours but I'm out of votes for the next 10 hours :-(

Comment: @CDSmith: Well my tooltip content comes from Table.....so how can i show it in Title?? i also tried to show them via alt as "alt="model.info"" bt its not displaying the content :(

Comment: @CDSmith Hey thanx its working I did this:
<img id="ok" src="../../Images/info.jpg" alt="tooltip" title="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Introduction)"/>

Answer (score 4):

`alt` attributes on `img` elements are used as **alternate text** in case the image does not exist. Some browsers display these as tool tips when hovering over the image, but its not standard.

You could use the `title` attribute to display a **tool tip** on hover of the image.

You should always provide an `alt` attribute when using images, this is best for accessibility (screen readers read the `alt` text), and will fail XHTML if you don't have the attribute.